# Can I upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 without any graphic driver issues?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

Some days ago I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my notebook.
All went good except for a incompatibility between my video card and the proprietary driver from AMD.
I've a ATI/AMD Mobility HD 4570 and AMD Catalyst 13.10 is the last driver that supports my card on Ubuntu.
For some reason this driver can't be installed on Ubuntu 14.04, so I revert to Ubuntu 12.04, and there I've not so much issues using the same driver.
Have you any idea what happen if I upgrade my Ubuntu to 14.04, now?
Could the installed driver no longer works in the upgrade process?
I really like to upgrade to a newer version, cause I can't use the latest releases of some software I need to work with.

Thanks in advance